# Matrix of rotation in $\mathbb R^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations, rotations

I'm attempting to teach myself basic multivariable calculus and so far finding some of the 3d visualizations a bit difficult. Here's an example:

Let $f: \mathbb R^{3} \longrightarrow \mathbb R^{3}$ be the rotation by $\pi$ about the line $x_1 = x_2$ and $x_3 = 0$ in the $x_1x_2$ plane. What is the matrix of $f$ with respect to the standard bases?

I suppose the line is the intersection of the plane $x_1 = x_2$ with plane $x_3 = 0$. However, it's unclear to me just what *thing* (for lack of a better term) is being rotated when we say "rotated **about** such-and-such **in** the so-and-so (plane, etc)".

Silly question, but what would be the difference from just rotating the *axes* $x_1$ and $x_2$ themselves by $\pi$, vs. what is specifically asked to be rotated in this problem?

The more images and visual intuitions one can offer, the better. Thank you.

Comment: $f$ is a function whose inputs are points and whose outputs are points in 3D space. So the *thing* being rotated is the point, the input of the function. The point is being rotated around the axis.

Comment: @elemelons Thanks. Can you say a little about what we really mean by rotate *about* a line? I mean, I can imagine a 2d vector in quadrant I being rotate by $\_pi$ counterclockwise: now it is in quadrant III. But it's unclear to me what is meant by rotating about an arbitrary line (say the line $y = x$). What is the difference when we rotate $\pi$ counter clockwise *about* $y = x$?

Comment: About the word ***about***: In your example above $\{x_1=x_2,x_3=0\}$ is obviously a line ***in*** the $x_1x_2$-plane. So let's forget about the word "in" and denote that line by $L$. Saying that we rotate about $L$ just means that we rotate around $L$ or that $L$ stays fixed in that rotation.

Comment: Kurt basically said this, but to emphasize the grammar here, the meaning in this context was "rotate about (the line [which happens to be] in the plane)" not to "rotate in the plane" or anything.

Comment: Thanks. After pondering this for a bit it dawned on me that the meaning must be around in the sense of 3d rotation around the line formed by $x_1 = x_2$ and $x_3 = 0$. Since no illustration accompanies this problem I think I was mentally stuck in a mode attempting to imagine *2d* rotation in something like the traditional $x-y$ coordinate plane but somehow "around" a line.

Answer (score 1):

For any vector $v\in\Bbb R^3$, write it as $v_1+v_2$, where $v_1$ is a multiple of $(1,1,0)$ (that is, $v_1$ belongs to the given line) and $v_2$ is orthogonal to $v_1$. Then $f(v)=f(v_1+v_2)=v_1-v_2$.

So, since $(1,0,0)=\left(\frac12,\frac12,0\right)+\left(\frac12,-\frac12,0\right)$, you have$$f(1,0,0)=\left(\frac12,\frac12,0\right)-\left(\frac12,-\frac12,0\right)=(0,1,0).$$By the same reason, $f(0,1,0)=(1,0,0)$. Finally, $f(0,0,1)=-(0,0,1)=(0,0,-1)$. Therefore, the matrix that you are after is$$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where does rotation by $\pi$ come into play in your solution? Wouldn't an orthogonal vector be one that is rotated $\frac{\pi}{2}$ from the perspective of another?

Comment: It comes to play when I write that $f(v_1+v_2)=v_1-v_2$; $v_2$ is mapped into $-v_2$ since it does a half-turn around the given line. Of course, $f(v_1)=v_1$ since $v_1$ belongs to the given line.

Comment: Added an answer with general rotation angle, $\phi$ instead of just $\pi$. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Construct an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ as follows

$ v_1 = ( 1, 1, 0 ) / \sqrt{2} $

$ v_2 = (-1, 1, 0 ) / \sqrt{2} $

$ v_3 = (0, 0, 1 ) $

Let $ A = [v_1, v_2, v_3] = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && -1 && 0 \\ 1 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && \sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix} $

Then given a point $P$, its representation in the above basis is given by

$ Q = A^T P = [q_1, q_2, q_3] $

Now, rotating $Q$ about the given line, is rotating $Q$ about the first basis vector, and since the rotation angle is $\pi$, the rotated image is

$ Q' = [ q_1, -q_2, -q_3 ] = B Q $ where $ B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && -1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && -1 \end{bmatrix} $

The corresponding coordinates in the standard basis are

$ P' = A Q' = A B Q = A B A^T P $

Therefore, the rotation matrix is

$ R = A B A^T = \dfrac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && -1 && 0 \\ 1 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && \sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && -1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && -1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1 && 0 \\ -1 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && \sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix} $

Calculating the product of the last two matrices,

$ R = \dfrac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && -1 && 0 \\ 1 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && \sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1 && 0 \\ 1 && -1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && - \sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix}$

Multiplying these two matrices yields

$ R = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && -1 \end{bmatrix} $

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain what about rotation by $\pi$ leads one to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ as a scalar?

Comment: The $ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $ has nothing to do the angle of rotation being $\pi$.  It comes from normalizing the basis vectors.

Comment: Gotcha. Can you briefly expand on how rotation by $\pi$ leads you to matrix $B$? That looks plausible at first glance, but my intuition is fuzzy.

Comment: You're rotating about $v_1$ by an angle of $\pi$, so the component along $v_1$ remains unchanged, while the components along $v_2$ and $v_3$ get negated.  This is similar (in planar rotations) to rotating a point $(x,y)$ about the origin by $\pi$, the image under the rotation is $(-x, -y)$.

Comment: Much appreciated. Last question(s). Why is $P$ multiplied by the transpose of $A$ as opposed to just $A$? Also, in the part that immediately follows 'Therefore, the rotation matrix is' where does the $\frac{1}{2}$ come from? Wasn't the original scalar $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: $P$ is expressed in the standard basis, therefore, $P = A Q$, hence $Q = A^{-1} P $, but because $A$ is orthogonal, then $A^{-1} = A^T$, hence $Q = A^T P $.  As for the $\dfrac{1}{2}$ it comes from multiplying $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $ by itself.

Answer (score 0):

The rotation matrix to rotate polar angle by $\alpha$:

$$ R(\alpha)= 
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
      cos(\alpha) & -sin(\alpha) & 0  \\
      sin(\alpha) & cos(\alpha) & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 1
  \end{array} } \right]$$

$$ T= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   0 & 0 & 1  \\
   1 & -1 & 0 \\
   1 & 1 & 0
  \end{array} } \right]$$

1. Change the line/axis $x_1 = x_2$, $x_3 = 0$ to $x_1 = x_2 = 0$ line/axis. This is done by multiplying by $T$.
2. Rotate by desired angle $\phi_r$ by multiplying $R(\phi_r)$.
3. change $x_1 = x_2 = 0$ axis to $x_1 = x_2$, $x_3 = 0$ by multiplying by $T^{-1}$

Overall Transform for rotating a vector $v$ angle $\phi_r$ about the $x_1 = x_2$, $x_3 =0$ line  is: $$v_{rotated} = T^{-1}R(\phi_r)Tv$$